# Node JS is throwing UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error invoking async function within another async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I am building a REST API using Node JS and Express JS.

I have a authService.js file that has the following function.

```
const  verifyVerificationToken = async ({ email, token }) => {
  try {
    let user = await userService.findUserByEmail(email).data

    if (! user) {
      return {
        error: true,
        code: 400,
        message: "Invalid account."
      }
    }

    let tokenModel = await VerificationToken.findOne({
      where: {
        userId: {
          [Op.eq]: user.id
        },
        verificationToken: {
          [Op.eq]: token
        }
      }
    })

    if (! tokenModel) {
      return {
        error: true,
        code: 400,
        message: "Invalid token."
      }
    }

    // check if the token is expired
    let now = new Date();
    if (now.getTime() < tokenModel.expiresAt.getTime()) {
      // check if the token is already verified
      if (tokenModel.verifiedAt) {
        // already verified
        return {
          error: true,
          message: "Token has already been used",
          code: 400
        }
      }

      // update the verifiedAt column
      await VerificationToken.update({
        verifiedAt: now
      }, {
        where: {
          id: {
            [Op.eq]: tokenModel.id
          }
        }
      })

      return {
        error: false
      }
    } else {
        // token is expired
        return {
          error: true,
          code: 400,
          message: "Token been expired."
        }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      error: true,
      code: 500,
      message: e.message
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, it is invoking findUserByEmail function of userService.js file. The following is the implementation of findUserByEmail function.

```
const findUserByEmail = async (email) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        email: {
          [Op.eq]: email
        }
      }
    })

    if (user) {
      return {
        error: false,
        data: user
      }
    } else {
      return {
        error: true,
        data: null,
        message: "User not found",
        code: 404
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      error: true,
      message: e.message,
      code: 500
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the code, it never returns the user, instead in the console, I am getting the following error.

```
(node:7600) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:467:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\collect_api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\collect_api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\collect_api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at login (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\collect_api\controllers\authController.js:38:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5)
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: This looks like a different file (`authController.js`) is setting headers after sending data, unrelated to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error means you have sent data to the client at least twice.
If you use express, it means you have called res.send (or equivalent res.render) multiple times.

therefore you have not given the right code sample in your question for me to help more.

Comment: Yes, I found the issue. The User sequlalize model is not imported in the userService.js. But the error message is totally irrelevant. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As for the error "never returns the user", you should change :

```
 let user = await userService.findUserByEmail(email).data
```

to :

```
 let user = (await userService.findUserByEmail(email)).data
```